# Merge multiple rows in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In **Table-01**, only one column(A/B/C/D) will be filled at a time. so end of the day I want to get all the filled columns values to one row. If column A filled 2 time in same day it should get the sum of those two. then the expected result is **Table-02**

Basically I want to reduced the number of rows in my table. How can I merge rows which have same date in to one row? **Time should be ignored.**

*Table-01*

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-14 00:00:00.000 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-10-14 11:32:19.350 | NULL | 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-10-14 20:56:33.217 | NULL | 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-10-19 15:04:10.760 | NULL | 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-10-19 16:21:28.553 | NULL | NULL | 2000 | NULL |
| 2020-11-02 15:57:41.277 | 1000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 08:20:54.137 | NULL | 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:38:06.117 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:39:04.137 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:41:53.857 | NULL | 3000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:43:07.780 | NULL | NULL | 4000 | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:43:51.780 | NULL | NULL | 4000 | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:44:32.330 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 13:46:44.293 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-05 07:43:25.553 | NULL | 3000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-05 07:44:44.853 | 4000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I want to convert this(^) to this(v)

*Table-02*

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-14 | 2000 | 2000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-10-19 | NULL | 1000 | 2000 | NULL |
| 2020-11-02 | 1000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-11-03 | 8000 | 4000 | 8000 | NULL |
| 2020-11-05 | 4000 | 3000 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: You have tagged with multiple incompatible databases.  Please remove the irrelevant tags, and use just a single tag for your actual database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to truncate the datetime to date and `group by` date as follows:

```
SELECT cast(date as date) AS Date,
       SUM(A) AS A, SUM(B) AS B,
       SUM(C) AS C, SUM(D) AS D
  FROM your_table
GROUP BY cast(date as date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate by `Date` in a `GROUP BY` query and then take the sum of each of the 4 columns.

```sql
SELECT
    DATE(Date) AS Date,
    SUM(A) AS A,
    SUM(B) AS B,
    SUM(C) AS C,
    SUM(D) AS D
FROM `Table-01`
GROUP BY
    DATE(Date);
```

The above is for MySQL.  A more general ANSI way of casting a column to date is `CAST(Date AS Date)`, but in any case the exact answer would depend on your actual database.